# Action always running even if Pull Request has a paths filter

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to get my Pull Request GitHub action to run only when there are changes in a specific folder `my-config`.

However, it is running when I have file changes outside of the `my-config` folder.

```yaml
name: Pull Request

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - my-config/**

concurrency:
  group: pr-${{ github.head_ref || github.run_id }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:

  Run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

Comment: this looks like it was a temporary issue on GH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this looks like it was a temporary issue on GH